# Fetch group wise contact using Google contacts api

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-contacts-api

Already I have followed the instruction of 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_single_contact_group for group data.

But whenever I tried to fetch group wise data using https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full, I only got the group id in the given array what they provided not the other data (like name, mobile number).

One of the given array is given below for better understand

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [gd$etag] => "YDwreyM."
        [id] => Array
            (
                [$t] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/rahmanarafat13%40gmail.com/base/6
            )

        [updated] => Array
            (
                [$t] => 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
            )

        [category] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [scheme] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind
                        [term] => http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#group
                    )

            )

        [title] => Array
            (
                [$t] => System Group: My Contacts
            )

        [content] => Array
            (
                [$t] => System Group: My Contacts
            )

        [link] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [rel] => self
                        [type] => application/atom+xml
                        [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/rahmanarafat13%40gmail.com/full/6?v=3.0
                    )

            )

        [gContact$systemGroup] => Array
            (
                [id] => Contacts
            )

    )
```

Don't get the other value like ['gd$name'] or ['gd$phoneNumbe'].

What should I do now ?

If any query please ask in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to think of contact groups as "labels". They are simply an attribute that exist on contacts. Fetching a group from the API only tells you metadata information about that label (basically just the name of it), but not the contacts that happen to have that label applied.

If you want to fetch contacts in a group, use the group filter parameter with the contact list endpoint. 
See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters where they fetch contacts with `updated-min`. Simply change `updated-min` to `group` and set the value to the group ID as shown in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Parameters

Comment: No @Blake it's not working.
Did you mean to do that 

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?group=office
where group is replaced by updated-min and office is my group(label) id value

Comment: the group ID is the full atom-style ID e.g. `"http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/you@gmail.com/base/2387528937582759825892758"`

Comment: yap @Blake I got it yesterday. Thanks.. :)